# Reputation graph dates are offset by 1 day

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, profile-page

I just noticed this issue.  I've never reported a bug before, so I don't know if this is a known problem, but it's reproducible for me, at least.

When I go to my profile, then go to the Reputation graph page, clicking on a date will show me the reputation changes for the *next* day.  Or at least, they're labeled as the next day. (Not sure if the problem is in the data or the labeling).

[image]

Is anyone else seeing this bug?

Comment: This is a thorough bug report, you did what you're supposed to.

Comment: It's definitely the labelling; the labels go up to yesterday, but the bars include today

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. If this is still occurring for you, can you give me details of what browser and OS you are using (as well as versions)?

Comment: Safari 8.0.6 on OS X Yosemite 10.10.3, and it's still occurring consistently for me.

Answer (score 4):

This was a fun problem, made more fun by the nature of it. It was a problem with the time epoch calculation used in the AJAX request that fetches the post data underneath. The interesting bit is that UTC users (included Oded!) weren't affected by it because their time offset matched.

A fix for all other users will roll out in the next build, it's just a small tweak to the JavaScript:

```
- var date = Date.UTC(d[0], d[1] - 1, d[2]),
+ var date = new Date(d[0], d[1] - 1, d[2]).getTime(),
```

Comment: Ha!  Very cool. :)